# Input doesn't show its value in console

Tags: javascript, input

I have written this:

```
var $emailLogin = document.querySelector('#emailLogin')
var Email = ''

function emailLogin () {
    Email = this.value
}

$emailLogin.addEventListener('input', emailLogin)

function myFunction() {
    console.log(Email)
}

$loginBtn.addEventListener('click', MyFunction)
```

But console doesn't show input's value [image: After Clicking the Login button it doesn't change]

It's empty like shown. I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the code that is causing a problem. You can likely use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).

Comment: In `function emailLogin () {Email = this.value}` the `this` will refer to the `window` object and not the input element.

Comment: So change `this.value` to `$emailLogin.value`

Comment: @cars10m I don't believe that's accurate, at least [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler), which say `this` is a reference to the element when bound using `addEventListener`...

Comment: Yes @HereticMonkey, you are right! I Never used  `this` in this context before. I eat my words!

Answer (score 2):

You should try and avoid global variables. The following will get you what you want without any "collateral damage" to the global name space:

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  console.log( document.querySelector('#emailLogin').value )
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="emailLogin"><button id="button">login</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you could try this:

```
document.getElementById('ButtonID').addEventListener('click',function(){
console.log(document.getElementById('emailLogin').value);
});
```

Comment: This would get the value once, upon page load. Then, when the button was clicked, it would log that value (likely the empty string) and set the variable `output` to undefined (the result of calling `console.log()`).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, I don't quite understand. This would work perfectly fine for the given question (ie returning vale of input.) Could you please explain the downvote?

Comment: What downvote? Also, we can see the edit history of your answer, so people are free to [view the revision of your answer my comment refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64936614/1).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey. Besides adding the one ); missing after my addEventListener and making the code more compact, the revision accomplished nothing, at least based in terms of what you said. The base response stayed the same (ie grabbing the value of input and returning,) so I see no error.

Comment: You moved the retrieval of the value of the text input inside the event listener, which alters what the value would be when the button is clicked. I mean, you made a mistake, no biggie, just own up to it, don't pretend like it didn't happen.

Comment: Yeah. you're right. I meant to declare that variable inside the function, but did it outside. It's fixed now